# batch file to exe to auto run when computer start

Tags: file, batch-file

I am a new programmer, i have created a batch file to open a website but i want that batch file to run when the computer starts.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off
:top
start iexplore.exe http://www.website.com
timeout 3
goto top
```

Comment: On the note of your code, that will open the website every ~3 seconds, is that intended behavior? I'll pend an edit to fix formatting too. You can just add 4 spaces to all lines with code in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `run` into windows search, type `shell:startup` in the prompt, press `enter`, Then, create a shortcut of your program, and move the shortcut into the `startUp` folder.

---

On note of your code, the start command should have a blank title as `""`, and quotes around the application name and parameters passed, like:

```
start "" "iexplore.exe" "http://www.website.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

While i do think Arescet's answer will work, i am more in favor of using Windows' Task Scheduler.

Simply create a new task :
[image]

Assign it's trigger to be `At Startup` :
[image]

and add a new action to `Start a program` giving it the path to your batch file:
[image]

I believe this is a cleaner approach which also provides you with logging and history should you decide to do more things in your batch file later on

Comment: You are the best man..... is their any way i can write the bat script to do the task schedular, i mean when user double click on bat file it should automatically added to task schedular

Comment: You taught me something. Fair enough.

Comment: I'm glad to hear. And yes it IS possible to automate the creation of the task using a batch file. See this guide for the full command and options that you can add : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx